# Finding unclosed queries in ADO.net

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I have some ADO.net code that is suddenly failing on my machine (luckily not any of the customer's!) due to "...ran out of resources." or "...connection closed." Looking in SQLSMS, I see that there are >55 open connections, which I guess is the error.

I **strongly** suspect this is due to too many open queries, and that's due to something (a recordset?) not being closed properly. Is there any *simple* way to list the SQL for these connections? The data in `sysprocesses` is always "AWAITING COMMAND". If not in SMS, perhaps in ADO?

Comment: Have a look at [WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/)

Comment: This is very useful, but only deepened the mystery. But this is an answer to my query, so I'll open a new question.

Comment: Time for a code review, I suspect, sounds like your code is leaking connections. `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` are all `IDisposable` objects that need to be properly managed via `using` blocks, or `try/finally` blocks with calls to `Close()` and `Dispose()`. Generally speaking people seem pretty good at handling `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`, but forget about `SqlDataReader` entirely, which is probably due to the low quality documentation examples for that class.